# How to stop a foreground service using a Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, foreground-service

Right now I have a foreground service that creates a notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

        Intent broadcastIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationReceiver.class);
        broadcastIntent.putExtra("toastMessage", "Test message");
        PendingIntent actionIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, broadcastIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        String channelId = "fcm_default_channel";
        Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.notification_uploading);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
                new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, channelId)
                        .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.animation_wifi)
                        .setContentTitle("Upload Photos")
                        .setContentText("1 photo uploading")
                        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.icon_back_black_arrow, "Cancel", actionIntent);


        startForeground(1111, notificationBuilder.build());
```

It has a cancel button that calls my Broadcast Receiver. How would I stop the foreground service inside the broadcast receiver class?

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("toastMessage");
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //When the foreground notification cancel button is clicked, this method is called
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the `stopForeground()` method can stop the service, but it is part of the Service class. it cannot be called from either the receiver.

Here are two solutions, you can realize that.

one solution, in your service class, registers a `BroadcastReceiver`,  when the aim `BroadcastReceiver` receives the message, send the broadcast to the service receiver.

```
//the service class
private final BroadcastReceiver closeService = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        /** here you can pass params, which you want to 
         * true use STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE,or directyly useing
         * STOP_FOREGROUND_REMOVE, you can also use  
         * remove nofitication 
         */
            stopForeground(int/boolean);
    };
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(""my.close.service"");
registerReceiver(mYReceiver, iFilter);

public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("toastMessage");
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // here to send it to service
       sendBroadcast(new Intent("my.close.service"))
    }
}
```

the other solution is in the broadcastReceiver restart the service, the in the `onStartCommad` method, according to the action to close it.

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG = "NotificationReceiver";
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String message = intent.getStringExtra("toastMessage");
        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        // here to restart the service
       startService(new Intent(this, YourService.class).setAction("STOP_ACTION"));
    }
}

// in the Service.java onStartCommand method, check the action and stop it.
public void onStartCommand(){
  if(intent.getAction() != null && 
   intent.getAction().equals("STOP_ACTION")) {
     stopForeground(true);
  }
}
```

in the end, if you are familiar with the `EventBus`, you can use it dispatch event to the service directly. or you can define the `BroadcastReceiver` as an inner class in the Service, then you also can called it directly

Comment: Is it possible to stop the current service by using it's on ```.addAction```? Instead of using Broadcast Receiver

Comment: @Lenoarod,   stopForeground() method does not take Notification_ID. It either takes a boolean or int (flags), but not notificationID.

Comment: @user3410835, yes, I use it as some params. I modify it.thanks

Comment: @Lenoarod, What is the difference between stopForeground() and stopSelf() ?? Do we need to call both of these methods to stop a foreground service ?? As of now i'm only using stopSelf() and it is working.